# Haw to find the asymptotic behavior of partial sum of series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics, taylor-expansion

What is the asymptotic behavior of the partial sum of Taylor series?

$$[x^n]f(x)(g(x))^k$$

where $f(x)=\frac{1}{1-4x}$ and $g(x)=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{2x}$.

Notice that:
$$(I)\quad f(x)=\sum\limits_{s=0}^\infty4^sx^s$$
$$(II)\quad g(x)=\sum\limits_{s=0}^\infty \frac{1}{s+1}\binom{2s}{s}x^s$$
$$(III)\quad (g(x))^k=\sum\limits_{s=0}^\infty \frac{k}{2s+k}\binom{2s+k}{s}x^s$$

In other words, while $k=n$, my question is what is the asymptotic behavior of
$$[x^n]f(x)(g(x))^n=\sum\limits_{s=0}^n 4^{n-s} \frac{n}{2s+n}\binom{2s+n}{s}\sim ?$$

Or more generally, when $k=\lfloor n^\alpha\rfloor ,0\leq\alpha\leq 1$.
$$[x^n]f(x)(g(x))^k=\sim ?$$

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: There is a formula in terms of an hypergeometric function. I do not think that you need it. For $n=100$, the ratio of the exact value to the nice approximation given by Antonio Vargas is $\approx 0.975441$

Comment: What motivated this calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a sketch, and I haven't checked all of the details.

Let

$$
S_n := \sum_{s=0}^n 4^{n-s} \frac{n}{2s+n}\binom{2s+n}{s}.
$$

The main difficulty is the binomial coefficient. It seems like $S_n$ is dominated by the terms where $s \approx n$, so we expect that we should have

$$
S_n \approx \sum_{s=0}^n 4^{n-s} \frac{n}{2s+n}\binom{3n}{n}
$$

in some sense, but if we compare plots of these they seem a bit off.

By carefully estimating the binomial coefficient we can prove that

$$
\binom{2s+n}{s} \sim \binom{3n}{n} \left(\frac{2}{9}\right)^{n-s} \exp\!\left\{-\frac{(n-s)^2}{12n}\right\} \tag{$*$}
$$

when $s = n - o(n^{2/3})$. This interval for $s$ should be plenty wide enough for our purposes. Thus we get

$$
\begin{align}
S_n &\sim \binom{3n}{n} \sum_{s=0}^{n} \frac{n}{n+2s} \left(\frac{8}{9}\right)^{n-s} \exp\!\left\{-\frac{(n-s)^2}{12n}\right\} \\
&\sim \binom{3n}{n} \sum_{s=0}^{n} \frac{n}{n+2n} \left(\frac{8}{9}\right)^{n-s} \exp\!\left\{-\frac{(n-n)^2}{12n}\right\} \\
&\sim \frac{1}{3} \binom{3n}{n} \sum_{r=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{8}{9}\right)^r \\
&= \,3\,\binom{3n}{n},
\end{align}
$$

which agrees with numerical experiments.

Generalizing this to other $k$ would require other estimates like $(*)$. Please let me know if you would like me to include the details of that asymptotic.

Comment: Nice approximation, for sure. I compared to the hypergeometric function and the asymptotics you provide is really nice.

Comment: Thanks @ClaudeLeibovici :)

Comment: Thank you very much! You really helped me a lot. If possible, could you give me some details for the more general case $k=n^\alpha, 0< \alpha<1$. It seems that we need to discuss three situations  ($\alpha<1/2, \alpha=1/2\  \text{and}\  \alpha>1/2$)  separately. Thanks again!

Comment: For $k$ small (fixed) relative to $n$, $$ [x^n]1/(1-4x)((1-\sqrt{1-4x})/(2x))^k \sim 4^n\,2^k(1+\Gamma(n+1/2)/(\sqrt{\pi} n!) )^{-k}$$